# Basic RX TestScheduler timing

Tags: c#, unit-testing, system.reactive

I'm using RX to do some (pretty basic) event subscription: -

```
public void StartListening(IObservable<Item> observable)
{
   subscription = observable
      .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5))
      .Where(Enumerable.Any)
      .Subscribe(events => service.DoStuffInBatch(events));
}
```

Now all I want is a set of unit tests that prove the behaviour of this method. Things like: -

- If I get data but time has not yet gone 5 seconds, we never call DoStuffInBatch.
- If I get data and time has passed 5 seconds, I call DoStuffInBatch with the data.
- If I don't get data and time has passed 5 seconds, I don't call DoStuffInBatch.
- If I get data over two windows e.g. some at 3 seconds and some at 8 seconds, I make two calls to DoStuffInBatch.

I have been reading through all the examples that Bart has put out (e.g. http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/14/testing-rx-queries-using-virtual-time-scheduling.aspx) but I'm really struggling with my tests. Here's an example: -

```
[Test]
public void StartListening_SomeDataAndBatchTimeHasNotPassed_DoesNotDoStuffInBatch()
{
    var scheduler = new TestScheduler();

    // Act - call the class under test, supplying a set of dummy data on the test scheduler
    listener.StartListening(GenerateTestData(5).ToObservable(scheduler));

    // Move the scheduler forward by one second
    scheduler.AdvanceBy(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).Ticks);

    // Assert that we never called the service as we haven't yet advanced 5 seconds
    Mock.Assert(() => mockService.DoStuffInBatch(null), Args.Ignore(), Occurs.Never());
}
```

However, this test fails. As soon as I call AdvanceBy, the subscription fires and calls DoStuffInBatch.

I'm clearly doing something wrong - but haven't got a clue what I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps you could try passing an `IScheduler` argument to the `StartListening` method, and use it to pass the `TestScheduler` instance to .Buffer(), or to a .SubscribeOn() call?

At runtime, you would just default to whatever would be a sensitive default for your case.

Comment: Hmmm, that might work. But do I really need to start exposing ISchedulers up to my code? I don't want subscribers of the IObservable to have to know to explicitly state what scheduler they want to use etc..

Comment: If you look at the Rx methods, a lot of them have overloads which take an `IScheduler`, so in the end this is not any different.

Comment: Hmmm, yes - but the docs also say that SubscribeOn should be very rarely used.

Comment: I didn't mean to imply that `SubscribeOn` should be used as a first choice. Of course if the method you are trying to use - `Buffer` in this particular case - takes an `IScheduler` argument, you should leverage that instead.

Comment: Indeed, supplying the TestScheduler to Buffer solves the problem. What I don't like is the fact that I have to do that - I would have preferred to be able to select the scheduler for the source observable and have that "flow through" the chain. I understand (I think) why that's not possible - it's just that I couldn't really find a decent blog / article out then simply on "how to unit test your code that uses RX" :)

Comment: Have you come across this MSDN [article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/06/14/testing-rx-queries-using-virtual-time-scheduling.aspx)? It's a bit long, but it is worth reading with attention. I read it diagonally and ended up discovering much of what is written there by myself, while writing a unit testing framework which deals with Rx.

Comment: Indeed I have - I even linked to it in my question. As I originally said - that article talks a lot about testing RX queries themselves but doesn't give a simple, step-by-step guide to testing behaviour of RX queries out.

Comment: Sorry, I realize now I missed the link. It is very interesting to get your feedback regarding the article, because I have been thinking about the utility of writing an article regarding Rx testing, as part of the documentation for the unit testing framework I am co-authoring (basically a thin productivity layer aggregating NUnit, ReSharper and PostSharp, and accompanied by a lot of guidance).